# What is the best way to check (on the product listing pages) if an items is already in the customer's wishlist

Tags: magento2

If anyone has implemented the functionality to show a different wishlist icon on the product listing pages when an item is already added to the wishlist, I want to know what is the best approach you have followed to check if an items is already in the customer's wishlist.

And how it will impact the product listing page speed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

for this we can remove add to wishlist button when product is already in wishlist.